# Using NUnit with TFS 2010? (specifically the reporting)

Tags: tfs, nunit

Has anyone gotten NUnit successfully integrated with TFS 2010? I can see how to nunit-console and get it run, the question is around the reporting. Has anyone got it to work reliably? I've seen: http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/ but the last activity is an alpha release in May. Has anyone tried this or another solution the six months since? Am I the only person since then to want more than MS-Test has to offer?

BTW there was an earlier version of this question but that was during the TFS 2010 Beta, I'm hoping other people have tried this since then.

Comment: Hmmm - so three things come to mind: No one is using TFS; No one is NUnit to Unit Test; or the few people using TFS just kump MSTest.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm struggling with the same thing. My knowledge of WF is non existent so I'm really struggling to get NUnit4TeamBuild to work. I did find this post: http://www.heikura.info/blog/publish-nunit-test-results-as-part-of-team-build-in-team-foundation-server-2010 the other day so it might be of some help to you.

Comment: People definitely use NUnit. Maybe we've just all been lucky enough to avoid TFS...

Answer (score 5):

I'm one of the contributors on NUnit4TeamBuild and it works fine in TFS2010, and I use it regularly with the various customers I deal with.

To get it going there are 2 options:
Option 1 - use the upgrade build process template with a 2008 style build project to get it working.
Option 2 - customise the default workflow template and replace the MStest testing activity with an InvokeProcess activity that calls the nunit command line.

I've got a [post](http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/08/how-to-build-vb6-apps-with-tfs-team.html) on VB6 compilation in TFS2010 (yuck!) that shows how the InvokeProcess activity works.  I really should do a post showing how the NUnit stuff works in 2010 as well, but just haven't got to it :-/

I'm also playing with creating a specific workflow activity that wraps the whole thing up in a nice way so it's easier to customise the workflow templates, but I haven't had much time to play with it.

Let me know how you go!

Comment: Not at this stage.  Happy to take contributions though :-)